# jQuery Masonry & WordPress

Tags: jquery, image, wordpress, gallery, jquery-masonry

I am trying to put together a WordPress gallery with jQuery Masonry, but it is not looking right.

This is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #D8D5D2;
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 240
  });
});
</script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div class="item"><img src="1.JPG" width="200" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="2.JPG" width="200" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="3.JPG" width="200" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="4.JPG" width="200" /></div>

...
</div>
```

And this is the output:

[image: Output]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I used Masonry a long time ago on my Wordpress site and it came out pretty nicely, only problem is I'm not sure what the code was because this was so long ago and the site doesn't exist anymore. Try adding the following to your CSS.

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: Also, make #container an overflow: hidden as well see what that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is awkward. Apparently the jquery.masonry.min.js was nowhere to be found, and the moment I did add it to the folder it started working perfectly! Thank you everyone for your kind suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

The first thing that stood out at me immediately was this line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It should be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nah, `//` is ok - it's equivalent of using https or http depending on what was used to load the page

Comment: Yeah, no, that didn't do anything, but thanks for telling me about that.

Comment: Aha, I learned something new today, thanks @c2h5oh. Jessica, did you try the [imagesLoaded](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html) plugin?

Comment: @Edenbauer How can I implement that? I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Replace your current mansonry init code with that shown [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html). It's the one under the "imagesLoaded plugin" heading. Basically you're wrapping the init code inside `$container.imagesLoaded(function(){});`

Comment: That didn't do anything either.

Comment: First of all, c2h5oh is right. Second, that's not the solution to the OP's problem, which was simply not loading the plugin.